# Which GL blend mode for blending the same color in source and destination, and getting the same color back?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I have an texture that is with a solid background (let's say navy blue, #000080) and white text on it.  Even though the texture is a single file with both background and text, I'd like to cause just the text to fade out.

I've prepared a second texture, just solid navy blue without any text.  I'd like to "fade" the text out by modifying the texture's alpha layer, until just the second texture (blue with no text) remains.

My problem is that when I start making the front layer (color + text) transparent, the text fades out as I expect, but the resulting blue is darker.  The blue I see is the background color blue (#000080), tinted dark by the semitransparent layer in front of it.  After some reading, it looks like I want to modify OpenGL's blend mode for this part.

I'm looking for a blend mode that generates:

```
#000080 + #000080*tranparency = #000080
#000080 + #FFFFFF*transparency = #FFFFFF*transparency
```

I've tried `GL_MIN` and `GL_MAX`, but those don't seem to be the ones I'm looking for here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need anything more than just:

```cpp
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glBlendEquation(GL_ADD);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

Which corresponds to the following:

```
original_pixel  = [0, 0, 0.5, 1]
incoming_pixel = [0, 0, 0.5, 0.5]

final_pixel = incoming_pixel * 0.5 + original_pixel * (1 - 0.5);
```

Which should leave the colour intact.

You shouldn't need the second texture - just draw an untextured quad with the correct colour.